# How to bind the event "pageshow" for an external HTML file with JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I´m developing a web app using JQuery Mobile (ver 1.3.0). If a have only one HTML file, I can bind the "pageshow" event to the page div:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Funil de Vendas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var nice = false;
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $("#other_page").bind('pageshow',function() {
                alert('The page was called!');
            });     
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
        <div data-role="page" class="Page" id="home_page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <a data-role="button"  href="#other_page" data-inline="true" style="width:300px;">Iniciar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div data-role="page" class="Page" id="other_page">
        <div data-role="content">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</body></html>
```

How can I do the same using multiples HTML files. I cannot bind to the page the because this div is in another HTML file.

```
<div data-role="page" class="Page" id="home_page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button"  href="other_page.html" data-inline="true" style="width:300px;">Iniciar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want to call to do something to a "X" page which is existing in multipage template? If so, assign a uniqe ID for each `div` with `data-role="page"`. i.e. `id="page1"`, `id="page2"`,...etc

Comment: Thanks @OmarNew2PHP. I´m using multipage template but with separate html files to each page.

Comment: Ok, got you. `href="other_page.html#pageX"` where `#pageX` is the ID of the `div` with `data-role=page` attribute.

Comment: @OmarNew2PHP, let me try be more clear. I have 2 HTML files. The first one is the index.html. It contains all javascripts and css references. The second one is the "other_page.html". It contains only the <div data-role="page">...</div> stuffs. The second page is load using AJAX by the JQuery Mobile framework itself. I´m trying to bind the event "pageshow" when the button is clicked on index.html. Thanks!

Comment: `Pageafterload` or `pagebeforeload` instead of `pageshow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways here:

**First solution.** In case you are using multiple HTML files and all of them are loaded with an ajax (this is a standard jQuery Mobile way of page loading). In this case all of javascript must be loaded into the first html file, because jQM will load only BODY content of other html files.

### Example :

**index.html :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
                        alert('This is a first page!');
                    });

                    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
                        alert('This is a second page!');                
                    }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h3>First page</h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                        <a data-role="button" id="some-btn" href="second.html">Open next page</a>                        
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**second.html :**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h3>Second page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
                This is a second page
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
```

**Second solution.** In case you have multiple HTML files but all your pages are linked wit links having rel="external" attribute or ajax is turned of on app level. In this case every html page must have its own HEAD and BODY. And every page must have it own javascript.

### Example :

**index.html :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
                        alert('This is a first page!');
                    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h3>First page</h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                        <a data-role="button" id="some-btn" href="second.html" rel="external">Open next page</a>                         
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**second.html :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){       
                        alert('This is a second page!');                
                    }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h3>Second page</h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                    This is a second page
            </div>

            <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: is `preventDefault();` required here?

Comment: No, because we don't want to prevent any action.

Comment: Thanks @Gajotres but your answer was not what i was looking for. My problem relates to how can I bind an event to an HTML element that is not already loaded in the DOM. Because the page is not yet loaded, I´ve not figured out how I could use the JQuery "bind" method to create an event handler to a div not yet loaded. Digging deeper with google I´ve found the simple solution to my problem. Just use the "live" JQuery method. "LIVE" can work with elements created after the page has been loaded (the case with DOM contents loaded with AJAX requests). By the way, thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? on work just  the same. If you bind it like it bind it in my example: $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){ it will wait for the future element, but if you bind it like this: $('#second').on('pagebeforeshow', function(){ it will try to bind on an existing element. Also live is deprecated in last jQuery version, and only way to bind it is by using .on(