# jQuery Mobile load some data before show

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to load some data with ajax and manipulate the DOM of a given "detail page". BEFORE the page is being shown. Important is that nothing of the "detail page" should be visible till all of the loading and manipulating of this page has finished. During the loading process the loading widget should also appear.

I tried this with:

```
$( '#page_series_detail' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event)
{
    AjaxSeriesDetail();
});
```

But in this case all of the loading and manipulating happens after the page is being shown.
Has anyone a hint for me ?

Comment: `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page-id", function() { Ajax here});` check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203560/how-to-bind-the-event-pageshow-for-an-external-html-file-with-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/) event of jQuery Mobile. This event will fire before showing the page to the user.

As per the documentation

> Triggered on the "toPage" we are transitioning to, before the actual
>   transition animation is kicked off.